# View not getting inserted

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

I am trying to add an empty view with height *30dp* below my *gridview* but unfortunately, I am not able to see the expected result.
The only thing visible is *gridview*.

How to display the empty *view* after all contents of *gridview* are rendered?

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/list"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my current output.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

There are many workarounds you could use to achieve what you're looking for.

In my opinion, using a dedicated library could be the best options for lightness.

Have a look at this: [GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter](https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter)

From the docs:

```
GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter gridView = (GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter) v.findViewById(R.id.ly_image_list_grid);

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View headerView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.test_header_view, null);
View footerView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.test_footer_view, null);
gridView.addHeaderView(headerView);
gridView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Comment: still...only gridview is visible.

Comment: Have you copied the entire layout? Take care that the root should be a LinearLayout with orientation vertical

Comment: I did the same... Still, its the same. :(

Comment: What you code does is that it adds a static view at the bottom of screen. I dont want that. I want to add an extra view after my gridview is  fully rendered, i.e. when I scroll to the last element of my gridview, I need an extra view below it (and not necessarily below the parent bottom).

Comment: Oh now I got it! Sorry! I'll edit my answer in a few minutes

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. Is there any way to do the same without using an external library?